# SVProgressHUD on showing alert inside NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios

I have a button for registration,by clicking this I am adding registration operation to NSOperationQueue, but my problem is, if username field is blank alert is not appearing.Someone please suggest me adding registration related task to NSOperationQueue a correct approach or not

```
- (IBAction)Register:(UIButton *)sender {

  NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
  NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                    selector:@selector(loadDataWithOperation)
                                                                      object:nil];
 [queue addOperation:operation];

}

- (void) loadDataWithOperation {


    if(username.text.length==0)
    { NSLog(@"loadDataWithOperation");

    [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Enter User Name"];
    }

 else

    {
      //cose for registration

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
if ([username.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
          UIAlertView *alert [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please fill all the fields." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

          [alert show];
        }
```